# Elixir transforming list of lists into one list

Tags: elixir

I have the following list:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4,5], [6,7,8], [9]]
```

And I want to get

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Duplicate of [How do I flatten a nested list in Elixir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68285424/how-do-i-flatten-a-nested-list-in-elixir)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`List.flatten/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/1.12/List.html#flatten/1) :

```
iex> List.flatten [[1, 2, 3], [4,5], [6,7,8], [9]]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```